# Tracing bitmap with actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I wonder if there is a function in ActionScript that can let me trace a bitmap file on the fly though scripting: something like myimg.TraceBitmap(), instead of having me to open a *.fla and work it there.

Comment: i don't understand your question.  you want to output each pixel's color of an image as a debug trace statement?

Comment: I guess you are not familiar with Adobe Flash (sorry if otherwise), with Adobe Flash you can trace bitmap and turn bitmap image into vector image which resolution independent^^

Comment: oh... trace as in tracing a drawing, like in Illustrator, not trace as in trace(), like in Flash/AS3:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#trace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native method to vectorize, but I found a package online that might worth a try.

Have you tried this one? 
http://coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=6

Rob

Comment: Thx...I will check through the packet.

Comment: Awesome library...I will take it as a brilliant answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Im presuming that you mean like the illustrator function to turn a bitmap into a vector? in which case I pretty sure there isnt such a function to run on the fly.